# Find key words on File name using regex

Tags: regex, keyword

I need to process files that have some key word (eg. "BOOK") in their names. The files naming conventions:

This solution works. But it's case sensitive. But how do I make it case insensetive

```
.*?-BOOK-.*?\.csv
```

When i have my file like "sometext-**BOOK**-sometext.csv" it works
But when my file is all lower case "sometext-**book**-sometext.csv" it does not catch this file.

Comment: Use `[bB][oO][oO][kK]`

Comment: What language, what tool you use? Is a leading inline modifier `(?i)` an option for it?

Comment: Most languages provide a way to specify that the regex should match case-insensitively. In Python use the `re.I` flag, in JavaScript or PHP use the `i` modifier after the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
(?i).*?-BOOK-.*?.csv
```

`(?i)`: This is a flag placed at the beginning of the regex to enable case-insensitive matching throughout the entire pattern.

`.*?`: Matches any character (zero or more times, non-greedy) - This captures any text before "-BOOK-".

`-BOOK-`: Matches the literal string "-BOOK-".

`.*?`: Matches any character (zero or more times, non-greedy) - This captures any text after "-BOOK-".

`.csv`: Matches the literal string ".csv" to ensure it's a CSV file.